# RequireJs trouble with WordPress 3.9+

Tags: javascript, wordpress, backbone.js, requirejs

When trying to develop a plugin using RequireJs I've run into some problems with WordPress.
Or probably more specific WordPress Editor functions.

I get the following js error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined
```

When I test with older versions of WordPress things runs smoother, and like the error reveals WordPress implemntation of Backbone seems to be the problem.

Any idea how to work aroud this?

Comment: could you please attach you requrejs.config code

Comment: I've abandoned the use of RequireJs in WordPress back-end since that's where the problem occurs. Using RequireJs in front-end works. From what I've understood WordPress 3.9+ now uses Backbone for some things and that might conflict with RequireJs define-method. Anyone who could confirm this?